# Постраничный вывод

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите пожалуйста решить вот такую задачу. Есть у нас СУБД с данными и индексацией по ID, при этом бывает что ID расположены не по порядку(записи удаляются), то есть для вывода всех записей использую mysql fetch array до потери пульса через while. А как мне ограничить вывод mysql fetch array через while скажем 50 первыми записями? И как взять допустим второй набор 50 записей, третий?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Если нужен постраничный вывод, то можно сделать так:
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
// Переменная хранит число сообщений выводимых на станице 
$num = 50; 
// Извлекаем из URL текущую страницу 
$page = $_GET['page']; 
// Определяем общее число сообщений в базе данных 
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM Имя базы данных";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query1); 
$posts = mysqli_num_rows($result);
// Находим общее число страниц 
$total = intval(($posts - 1) / $num) + 1; 
// Определяем начало сообщений для текущей страницы 
$page = intval($page); 
// Если значение $page меньше единицы или отрицательно 
// переходим на первую страницу 
// А если слишком большое, то переходим на последнюю 
if(empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1; 
  if($page > $total) $page = $total; 
// Вычисляем начиная к какого номера 
// следует выводить сообщения 
$start = $page * $num - $num;
$query = "SELECT * FROM Имя базы данных WHERE ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $start, $num";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

...

  // Проверяем нужны ли стрелки назад

    if ($page != 1) $pervpage = '<a href=' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page=1><<</a> 
    <a href=' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page='. ($page - 1) .'><</a> ';

// Проверяем нужны ли стрелки вперед

if ($page != $total) $nextpage = ' <a href=' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page='. ($page + 1) .'>></a> 
<a href=' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page=' .$total. '>>></a>';

// Находим две ближайшие станицы с обоих краев, если они есть

if($page - 2 > 0) $page2left = ' <a href=' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page='. ($page - 2) .'>'. ($page - 2) .'</a> | '; 
if($page - 1 > 0) $page1left = '<a href=' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page='. ($page - 1) .'>'. ($page - 1) .'</a> | ';
if($page + 2 <= $total) $page2right = ' | <a href=' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page='. ($page + 2) .'>'. ($page + 2) .'</a>';
if($page + 1 <= $total) $page1right = ' | <a href=' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page='. ($page + 1) .'>'. ($page + 1) .'</a>';

// Вывод меню 
echo $pervpage.$page2left.$page1left.'<b>'.$page.'</b>'.$page1right.$page2right.$nextpage;

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM таблица ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT номер_страницы*50,50;
```

где

```
ORDER BY id ASC
```

-- сортировка по id.

**UPD.** Нумерация страниц, естественно, начинается с нуля.

Answer (score 0):

```
обычно делают с помощю GET запроса. Например, у вас 10к вопросов, то
берете лимитом 50 первых записей, при условий что нет !isset($page).
 В противном случае `select * from .... where ... limit $page*50,50;`
Не забываем еще, про количестве "отображаемых",соседних страниц...
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM таблица ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT (**номер_страницы-1**)*50,50;

Answer (score 0):

используйте решение, характерное для всех крупных проектов.

там не делается постраничный вывод на основе OFFSET, LIMIT, т.к. оно имеет несколько существенных недостатков:

1. невозможно применять на выборках с большим смещением OFFSET, слишком много захватывается данных в запросе.
2. если данные часто обновляются, то может случиться так, что при новой подзагрузке данных в них окажутся уже ранее выведенные.

лучше использовать выборку со смещением по id или date (решение для вывода наиболее свежих записей по ID):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < offset ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50;
```

на старте offset сделайте максимально возможным для данной колонки (если INT, то 4294967295). далее отправляете в запросе минимальное значени ID из текущей выборки и при последующем оно возвращается уже в качестве нового offset.

тоже самое применимо и для колонки date, если данные упорядочены по дате, а ID идут не в хронологическом порядке.

также не забудьте использовать индексы (при простых запросах с date - индекс по этой колонке, при сложных запросах с несколькими условиями делаем составной индекс строго в порядке следования условий WHERE и ORDER BY, например (cond_1, cond_2, date)).