# Постраничный вывод из запроса

Tags: php, sql

Уважаемые пользователи, помогите пожалуйста в данном коде

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if($conn == false){
     print("Не получилось подключиться!");
} else {
     $sql = ("SELECT * FROM  `users` ORDER BY ID DESC  LIMIT 20");
     $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
     if($result == false){
        print("Запрос не выполнен.");
     } else {
        while($raw = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
           print ('<div class="news-block"> '.$raw['lastname'].' '. $raw['name'].' '.$raw['patronymic'].' '.$raw['birhday'].' '.$raw['adress'].' '.$raw['com'].' '.$raw['times'].' <hr>☝</div>');
        }
     }
}
echo '<div id="nav"><a href="/list.php">Просмотреть полный список</a></div>';
```

P.s x2 За помощь будет небольшое но все же поощрение

Comment: вон справа похожие вопросы, там есть ответы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/245383/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4?rq=1

Comment: Скорее всего мне будет сложно интегрировать это в свой код не повредя при этом весь сайт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так выходит, исходя из вашего кода:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
$pageNum = $_GET['pageNum'] ?: 0; // get параметр номера страницы
$pageSize = $_GET['pageSize'] ?: 10; // кол-во элементов на странице
if($conn == false){
     print("Не получилось подключиться!");
} else {
     $queryLimit = $pageNum * $pageSize;
     $sql = ("SELECT * FROM  `users` ORDER BY ID DESC  LIMIT {$queryLimit}, {$pageSize}");
     $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
     if($result == false){
        print("Запрос не выполнен.");
     } else {
        while($raw = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
           print ('<div class="news-block"> '.$raw['lastname'].' '. $raw['name'].' '.$raw['patronymic'].' '.$raw['birhday'].' '.$raw['adress'].' '.$raw['com'].' '.$raw['times'].' <hr>☝</div>');
        }
     }
}
echo '<div id="nav"><a href="/list.php">Просмотреть полный список</a></div>';
```

p.s. советую использовать библиотеки для работы с БД, обработки `GET`, `POST` параметров и т.п.

Comment: Очень хороший вариант, а можно дополнить переключение по страницам? 
И перевожу вам 300р на карту
Сойдет?

Comment: @XsEeNoNXe нет, вы ресурсом ошиблись, у вас есть `$pageNum`, можете в `echo`, вывести ссылку `/list.php?pageNum={$nextPageNum}`, а `$nextPageNum = $pageNum + 1`. `$prevPageNum = $pageNum - 1` по аналогии

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: @XsEeNoNXe  Почитай правила ресурса [tour]. и если ответ помог - поставь рядом с ним галочку.